# web scrapping, is there a reason why src doesn't work when I try to get the contents within src

Tags: python, web-scraping

[Kanye West Wikipedia Webscrape First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9NmR.png)

[The html from the Kanye wiki for the first image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lG90.png)

I'm confused on why it isn't working. I feel like it can't be because src doesn't exist, because it does...? My apologies if this is an obvious fix, I'm fairly new to coding, and just started learning web scraping today. If anyone has any good resources to learn better, please lmk!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28006690/getting-a-particular-image-from-wikipedia-with-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 1):

Please post your source code next time. This code will extract all image src values.

```
find_all_images = bs.find_all('img')
for image in images:
    if image.has_attr('src'):
        print(img['src'])
```

Comment: what is source code? sorry, I'm new to coding

Comment: Your Python code.

Comment: my first link is my python code, no?

Comment: Post the code here so we can copy your code and reproduce the code locally. If it's an image the person that wants to help you has to retype it all.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your `comp` variable is a `Tag` object. You'll need to look at it's contents and retrieve the attributes you want that way.

`print(comp.contents[0].attrs['src']`